# How do I make a function in Python which recursively "eats" the last letter of the input string and spits it out again once the string has length 1?

Tags: python, string, recursion

For example, if I call `inout("hello")` it should print:
"""hello
hell
hel
he
h
he
hel
hell
hello
"""

I've tried the following:

```
def inout(w):
    if len(w) == 1:
        return w
    else:
        return w + "\n" + inout(w[:-1])
```

But calling `inout("hello")` returns:

```
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

Comment: Does this have to be a recursive function, or will any code be enough?

Comment: @match Preferably a recursive function, but any simple code will do. It's part of our introduction to Python on my education so it's just an exercise, but I want to understand how I can be done in a simple way (and our lecturer has written "use recursion" as a hint).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than counting down and then trying to 'change direction', since this is always going to be a symmetrical 'mirror' of the same 'words', we can more easily generate the list of 'words' in one direction and then print it both backwards (skipping the duplicate single-character):

```
from itertools import chain

text = "hello"
words = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    words.append(text[0:i+1])
# words is now: ['h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', 'hello']
print("\n".join((x for x in chain(reversed(words), words[1:]))))
```

This outputs:

```
hello
hell
hel
he
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```